# Filter features from a polygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, feature-filter

I want to filter features from a polygon shapefile in QGIS using a list of numbers that occur only in one column of the attribute table.

For example:
My attribute table has 20 columns. One of them is named "telephones". I have a txt file that only contains one telephone number per row. How can I filter all features that assign to each number?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to ***join*** shapefile to txt file. You should add your .shp and .txt files to QGIS and join them based on the filter field. You can follow tutorial at https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/joining-data/.

Comment: "feature" in ('45','87','988',4687','444')
This is what I was looking for